# Magento custom file upload not working in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento, file-upload

In my web site I want to add custom file upload function in front end. So I just using Magento default custom option. After upload image when I click to add to cart button it shows "Please specify product required option's".

Comment: Is this your custom option of product ?

Comment: @TBI yes.. its product custom option

Comment: Please check this link if it makes any difference with your custom option http://www.solvingmagento.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/file_custom_option_1.png

Comment: @TBI no there is no difference at backend also i cand upload image in front end. if I click add to cart button in front end am getting error

Comment: Voting to close as containing insufficient information to diagnose the issue.